# Why does Wine insist on removing systemd?

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, wine, uninstall

I'm on a fresh install of Mint 18.2, and I'm adding a bunch of multimedia tools. I would like to have LMMS use VST files, as well; but this requires Wine as (curiously) VSTs are all portable executables.

I'm not a big fan of Wine, I have Windows for that; but so be it. However, before installing it, I see that it requires the removal of systemd. I don't know why this is, and honestly I'm not a huge fan of systemd either; but it serves a pretty critical role. I'm not ready to ditch it just yet.

It's probably safe; this is through the Software Manager. However it seems appropriate to at least do a little digging first.

Does anyone know why Wine insists on removing systemd? Is it replaced with one of these other packages? Am I safe in doing this?

[image]

Comment: Is not wine fault but a conflict with the packages, try aptitude and then type no in one or more solutions, until find the better. Another thing is wine from your distro official repository?

Comment: Yes it is, as I said, it is a fresh install. What I need to know is, will I be alright after removing systemd?

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin Removing systemd would not end well at all. That is your init system

Comment: @Fox Yeah that's what I'm figuring. I know there are a few substitutes, but I'm not seeing them in that list. Wine isn't worth it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting results... seems it doesn't actually need to remove systemd after all. Not according to apt-get & apt, and not according to Synaptic. I got Wine on here with a number of other dependencies, and compiled LMMS's most recent release (everything, including VST, now working beautifully).

I think my question just got boiled down to "Why does Software Manager insanely suggest that I remove systemd?" Which is kind of a different question, and makes this problem resolved.

I'm honestly wondering if this is even a bug of some kind.

Comment: Linux mint 18 did not use systemd as default, unlike xenial.  You can control it with 

    `ps -p 1 -o comm=`